# Cocos2d ClippingNode and Alphathreshold in Javascript / Browser

Tags: javascript, canvas, cocos2d-js

i am trying tp use a png as a mask in Cocos2d-JS 
like so:

```
this.mask=cc.Sprite.create(cache.getSpriteFrame("bar_mask"));
this.maskedFill = cc.ClippingNode.create(this.mask);
this.maskedFill.setAlphaThreshold(0.5);
```

But it does not work ...
I found in other posts, that I have to enable the stencil buffer like
CCSetupDepthFormat: @GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES

But I have no idea how / where to do that in Cocos2d-JS

can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me without any additional depthFormat settings.
I'm using single-file engine cocos2d-js-v3.7.js
Here's the minimal code (hope it helps):

```
var game = cc.Layer.extend({
  init:function () {
    this._super();

    backgroundLayer =  cc.LayerColor.create(new cc.Color(40,40,40,255), 320, 480);

    var target = cc.Sprite.create("resources/doge.png"); /*child to clip*/
    var mask = cc.Sprite.create("resources/doge-mask.png"); /*mask*/

    var maskedFill = new cc.ClippingNode(mask);
    maskedFill.setAlphaThreshold(0.9);
    maskedFill.addChild(target);
    maskedFill.setPosition(144, 224);

    backgroundLayer.addChild(maskedFill,0);
    this.addChild(backgroundLayer);

  }
});
```

Comment: Aha, thanks! It seems the quality is not very fine and i have a very delicate graphic ... so i just thought it is not working ...